# Generate xml attributes

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xelement, xattribute

I have to create an xml file, that contains an element with attributes like:

```
 <element 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://test.xsd" 
     xmlns="http://test2" 
     xmlns:xsi=http://test3>
```

I tried:

```
 XNamespace ns = "xsi";            
 var root = new XElement("element",
                       new XAttribute(ns + "schemaLocation", "http://test.xsd"), // (I)
                       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns, "http://test2"),         // (II)
                       new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://test3"), // (III)
```

But the only thing that is generated fine is (III):

```
 xmlns:xsi=http://test3
```

(I) is generated like:

```
 p1:schemaLocation="http://test.xsd" xmlns:p1="xsi"
```

and (II) is not generated because the line doesn't compile.

Any idea on how I could generate these attributes?

Thank you,
L

EDIT - also found it here: [Creating XML with namespaces and schemas from an XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335135/creating-xml-with-namespaces-and-schemas-from-an-xelement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const string ns = "http://test2";
const string si = "http://test3";
const string schema_location = "http://test.xsd";

XNamespace xns = ns;
XNamespace sinsp = si;

     XElement xe = new XElement(xns + "element",
           new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", si),
           new XAttribute(sinsp+ "schemaLocation", schema_location),
           new XElement(xns + "sometag", "somecontent")
        );

     return xe;
```